# Unflag other users flag

Tags: 7, flags

I have a site where people can sell their own items, so when a user creates a new product there is a flag "request product" that is added on the content.

I want the user who created the product to be able to unflag requests from other users.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module as it integrates very well with the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module.

Check out the [Flag video series](http://nodeone.se/en/node/26) by Johan Falk. Part 7 is specifically regarding Rules.

In short you're looking to generate a list of users that have flagged a node and then with built in Rules actions, unflag them.

Comment: the website you mentioned is unavailable. Could you add to you answer how the Rules actions are built? Does one use "rules link" module?

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the "[Flag Clear](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_clear)" module. This module will offer a much more straightforward approach to your problem than using a twisted Rules logic.

This module provides functionality to remove user flags for nodes and other entities.